# Print big r matrix in Latex with Sweave, knitr or Rmd

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, sweave

Printing big r matrix in Latex. I came out with this function which loops over rows.. is there any smarter way to do it?
Is there a way to create a loop in Latex syntax?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<echo=FALSE>>==
M <- head(mtcars)

tab_row <- function(i){paste0(
rownames(M)[i], " & ", 
M[i,01], " & ",
M[i,02], " & ",
M[i,03], " & ",
M[i,04], " & ",
M[i,05], " & ",
M[i,06], " & ",
M[i,07], " & ",
M[i,08], " & ",
M[i,09], " & ",
M[i,10], " & ",
M[i,11], " \\\\\\\\ ", "\\\\hline \n")
}

tab <- rep("", nrow(M))
for (i in 1:nrow(M)) {tab[i] <- tab_row(i)}
tab <- paste(tab, collapse = '')
@

\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccc}
\Sexpr{tab}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `knitr::kable` to print.  I think you'll get what you want with `knitr::kable(M, format = "latex", vline = "", align = "c")`.  Some of the args are undocumented, including `vline`; you need to look at `knitr:::kable_latex` to see what's available.